# X11 apps (specifically xman) on a large 4K TV are tiny -- how does one upscale x11 apps? OR Have any recommendations for a man page GUI?[Ubuntu 20.04]

Tags: xorg, display, display-resolution, manpage

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Display: 4096 × 2160 on a 4K TV
Display Settings: Use interface scaling: Double (Hi-DPI)
```

Howdy friends. I am rocking a 65-inch (165cm) TV as a monitor at 4K resolution on Ubuntu 20.04.

It's been a hassle to make things legible ever since I switched out a monitor for a TV, but for the most part, everything works. Still, it seems like every old, simple X app fails to be legible (or usable) , save for at a distance of nose-to-screen.

My primary use-case here is that I'm looking for a prettier version of user manuals as opposed to using terminal man pages, so if you can recommend anything that isn't `yelp man:$command`, `xman`, `man --html=chromium-browser $command`, `gman`, or "use vim, lol", I'm all ears.

With all of that said, here's a picture of the current situation:
[image: x11 miniscule text/menus]

This is a screenshot of my workstation while using the image-viewing app `feh` on a screenshot where I was trying to use `xman`. As you can see, terminal and window titles looks just fine. The xman page, shown in the window with "Manual Page" at the top, however, is absolutely microscopic. Further, if you look closely at the little white boxes next to the xman box, you will see the ridiculously tiny "feh" menu.

(I realize that the image is quite legible in the screenshot and that the Terminal text looks huge, but pretend you are 10-feet/3m away from it to get the idea).

Any idea on how to fix this system-wide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "run_scaled" tool. Basically it will scale up X windows with a set scaling factor (the default is 2). It does not work with some applications, but for xterm, xmgrace it works. Likely will work with xman as well.

Link to the relevant SO topic: [run_scaledtool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56177205/how-do-i-run-this-run-scaled-script-from-github)

Comment: Not addressing your scaling issues, but all the standard man pages are available at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ so you can read them in a browser. Still fixed-space font but easier to read and navigate than a terminal.

Comment: Y'know, I knew about this at one point or another because I had it hardcoded into a few aliases. I then proceeded to forget about it until you reminded me that it exists. Thank you.